# Loop through CSV files--issue completing task for each individual file

Tags: r, loops, csv

I'm attempting to loop through multiple CSV files and complete the same task for each file to save myself time. First, I ran 'list.files' to list all files in the folder (e.g., GPS_Collar33800_13.csv,GPS_Collar33801_13.CSV,etc). I then developed a loop but I'm struggling on how to structure the other parts of the code to work through each individual file. My end goal is to have 24 files that all look the same structurally and then I need to merge them all together into a master file. Another issue is that I need to list a unique ID for each file (Add column for collar ID, e.g., 33800,33801,33802,etc.) but I don't know how to easily do this without manually adding in a new unique ID by hand (if I knew that it was bringing in file GPS_Collar33800_13.csv first then I can make the AnimalID column value=33800 and do the same thing for GPS_Collar33801_13.csv and add in AnimalID column value=33801). The unique IDs are based on the file name. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
 ## List CSV files in folder
`files<-list.files()`

## Run a for loop to complete the same tasks for each
for (i in 1:length(files)){
## Read table
tmp<-read.table(files[i],header=FALSE,sep=" ")
## Keep certain columns
tmp1 <- tmp[c(2:5,9,10,12,13)]
#Name the remaining columns
names(tmp1) <- 
c("GMT_Date","GMT_Time","LMT_Date","LMT_Time","Latitude","Longitude","PDOP","2D_3D")
#Add column for collar ID
tmp1$AnimalID<-33800
#Cleanup dataframe by removing records with NAs
tmp1[tmp1 == "N/A"]  <- NA
tmp2<-na.omit(tmp1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
library(stringr)
## List CSV files in folder
files<-list.files()

big.df <- vector('list',length(files))

## Run a for loop to complete the same tasks for each
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  ## Read table
  tmp<-read.table(files[i],header=FALSE,sep=" ")
  ## Keep certain columns
  tmp1 <- tmp[c(2:5,9,10,12,13)]
  #Name the remaining columns
  names(tmp1) <- 
    c("GMT_Date","GMT_Time","LMT_Date","LMT_Time","Latitude","Longitude","PDOP","2D_3D")
  #Add column for collar ID
  tmp1$AnimalID<-str_match(files[i], 'Collar(\\d+)_')[,2]
  #Cleanup dataframe by removing records with NAs
  tmp1[tmp1 == "N/A"]  <- NA
  tmp2<-na.omit(tmp1)
  big.df[[i]] <- tmp2

}
final.df <- do.call('rbind', big.df)
```

It will require the `stringr` package and assumes your filenames all look like 'GPS_Collar33801_13.csv', etc.  It then reads in each file, stores it in a large list, moves to the next file... and when it's done, it mashes them all together in a data.frame called `final.df`.

Edit:  Just fixed the `str_match` argument.

Comment: @Buck2079 Glad to hear it :)  Would appreciate if you would accept the answer... although I'm not in it for the rep!  (I am.)

Answer (score 0):

So let me make sure before I begin that I understand the ask:

1. For each file in the folder,

   1. Import the file as a data frame
   2. Drop some columns
   3. Rename the remaining columns
   4. Set a column in the data frame to a value obtained from the file name
   5. Remove cases containing the string "N/A" anywhere
2. Then, combine each of the resulting data frames into one data frame by UNION-ing them (that is, adding the rows together because the columns should be the same).

It's critically important that you provide your data with any such question. If you can't provide your specific data, create some fake data that still demonstrates the problem at hand. Then, provide an example of what it should look like once the operations are complete. This reduces guesswork by the people answering your question.

So with all that said, let's get cracking.

Let's abstract away the sub-parts of task #1 by pretending that we have a function called `process_a_file` that will do steps 1-5 of each individual file and return a data frame. I can explain how that function works later.

For the "for each file" part, you need `lapply`. `lapply` runs a given function on each element of a list you provide, and returns a list of what the function returns:

```
results_list <- lapply(files, process_a_file)
```

This will return a list, where each element of the list is a data frame returned by `process_a_file`. Then you need a function to combine them - I recommend `bind_rows` from the package `dplyr`:

```
results_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(results_list)
```

And that's all you need to do!

So, now, what do we put in `process_a_file`? This is pretty easy - your code is mostly complete for doing this, but there are some different ways to do it that I prefer :)

```
process_a_file <- function(filename) {
    #???????
}
```

Step 1 is to import the file as a data frame. For this I recommend `read_delim` from the `readr` package - it's much faster than the default R methods, has nice defaults, and lets us tackle Step 5 at the same time by specifying that "N/A" means `NA`:

```
df <- readr::read_delim(filename, delim = " ", col_names = FALSE, na = "N/A")
```

For step 2, your way works, but I also recommend the `select` function from `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::select(df, 2:5,9,10,12,1)
```

You can also index columns with unquoted names, and drop columns with `-5` or `-column_name` too - and you can do step 3 at the same time!

```
df <- dplyr::select(
  df,
  GMT_Date = 2,
  GMT_Time = 3,
  LMT_Date = 4,
  LMT_Time = 5,
  Latitude = 9,
  Longitude = 10,
  PDOP = 12,
  `2D_3D` = 13
  )
```

Your way of renaming the columns is fine, too. By the way, if you start a column name with a number, you have to use this `backtick` syntax everywhere, so it's quite inconvenient and you should probably avoid it if you can.

Then finally, I recommend getting the ID from the file name using regular expressions. I'll assume you can write that regular expression since that's really out of scope - so you can use `basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)` to return the filename without the path or extension, and use `stringr::str_extract` to pop out the ID, which you then add to a column using dplyr::mutate

```
dplyr::mutate(df, animal_id = stringr::str_extract(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)), "THE REGEX GOES HERE"))
```

So now, putting this all together - using dplyr's piping syntax `%>%` to make it look nice:

```
process_a_file <- function(filename) {
  readr::read_delim(filename,
                    delim = " ",
                    col_names = FALSE,
                    na = "N/A") %>%
    dplyr::select(
      GMT_Date = 2,
      GMT_Time = 3,
      LMT_Date = 4,
      LMT_Time = 5,
      Latitude = 9,
      Longitude = 10,
      PDOP = 12,
      `2D_3D` = 13
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(animal_id = stringr::str_extract(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(filename)), "THE REGEX GOES HERE"))
}
results_list <- lapply(files, process_a_file)
results_df <- dplyr::bind_rows(results_list)
```